# Why is this not a circle?

Tags: plotting

```
sols = y /. Solve[(x - 4)^2 + y^2 == 4, y];
Plot[sols, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

When I plot it, I would expect a circle centered at x=4, y=0 with radius 2, but it becomes an ellipse ?

why is "AspectRatio -> 1" wrong ?

Comment: Set `AspectRatio -> Automatic` and try again.

Comment: @ J.M. yes, it works now... but why is AspectRatio -> 1 wrong ?

Comment: It is a circle. `AspectRatio` controls the physical size of the axis not the scale of the axis.  With `Automatic` it looks to the scale of the axis.  Not the case when you specify a particular ratio.

Comment: notice as the x range is 10 and the y range is 4 the plot aspect ratio to make the units square is `AspectRatio->4/10` (what `Automatic` does for you)

Comment: @george2079 okay, thanks a lot ! :)